# Java - Throttling SOAP API calls

Tags: java, web-services, implementation, throttling

I'm building a Java application which makes requests to a SOAP API. Certain methods that the API exposes are throttled and these methods have different throttling rates, ranging from 5 p/m to 100 p/m. It's not acceptable to limit all requests to 5 p/m as some methods (i.e. the ones with higher throttling limits) must be accessed more frequently.

How can I implement throttling control in my project which allows me to specify different throttling limits for different methods?

Cheers,

Pete

Comment: is this on a single thread? or can it make multiple requests to remote methods in parallell?

Answer (score 0):

Pete -

A couple of questions:

- Is this throttling being done on a per-user basis?
- Do your API calls include a way to uniquely identify the caller?
- What behavior are you looking for when the limits are exceeded?

One general approach is to have an internal method that tracks the user, the method called, and the rate at which it's allowed to be called, and returns a boolean indicating whether the user has exceeded their limits.  You want this method to be fairly lightweight so that the calculation doesn't impact performance of the rest of the system, since every API call will require this check.

Comment: Throttling is done on a limited/unlimited basis where all non-paid for accounts are limited in the same way and all paid-for accounts have unlimited access. I'm looking to make the application suspend until it's allowed to make a throttled request if it tries to make one but has used its allowance for the moment.